# T-SQL to Linq: converting the having datediff in a group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following data set in SQL and I need to convert it from TSQL to LINQ in C#.

```
create table #sampledata 
(
    name nvarchar(50),
    sampletime datetime,
    samplevalue decimal, 
    block int
);

insert into #sampledata (name, sampletime, samplevalue, block) values
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null, 10),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null, 10),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null, 13),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), null, 17),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), null, 3),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null, 9),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null, 9),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null, 12),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null, 15),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null, 15),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null, 16),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), 40.00, 0),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00, 0)
```

This the the T-SQL I am using to run against this data set

```
select 
    name,
    min(sampletime) as startdate, 
    max(sampletime) as enddate
from #sampledata where samplevalue is null
group by
    name, block
having datediff(minute, min(sampletime), max(sampletime)) >= 5
order by name, startdate
```

The grouping was quite easy to convert however I am not sure how to tackle the following the having clause and more specifically how to deal with datediff in c# using aggregates

```
having datediff(minute, min(sampletime), max(sampletime)) >= 5
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var query = (from s in sampledata
                         where s.block.HasValue == false
                         group b by new { Name = s.Name, Block = b.Block     } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             Name = g.Name,
                             StartDate = g.Min(a => a.SampleTime),
                             EndDate = g.Max(a => a.SampleTime)

                         });
```

Comment: so you already have LINQ to create the GROUP BY?  I guess your means of progress will depend on how you did that, see http://devkimchi.com/211/playing-group-by-and-having-clauses-with-linq/ can we see the LINQ?

Comment: Why don't you post what have you done. And btw, LINQ is too broad. LINQ to Sql? LINQ to Entities? or ?

Comment: I edited the question, adding code of what I have so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could write that query:

```
from x in Sampledata
where x.Samplevalue == null
group x by new { x.Name, x.Block } into g
let name = g.Key.Name
let startdate = g.Min(x => x.Sampletime)
let enddate = g.Max(x => x.Sampletime)
where SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(startdate.Value, enddate.Value) >= 5
orderby name, startdate
select new { name, startdate, enddate }
```

Just note that you likely won't get exactly the same query, but it should be close enough.

But if you're unable to use `SqlMethods`, the next closest thing you could do is this:

```
from x in Sampledata
where x.Samplevalue == null
group x by new { x.Name, x.Block } into g
let name = g.Key.Name
let startdate = g.Min(x => x.Sampletime)
let enddate = g.Max(x => x.Sampletime)
where (startdate.Value - enddate.Value).Minutes >= 5
orderby name, startdate
select new { name, startdate, enddate }
```